# Let MS Project 2010 assign resources to tasks?

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, gantt

Technical question concerning MS Project 2010:

- I have a Gantt with a list of tasks.
- For each task I have the work defined (ex: 2 wks).
- Each task can only have one person (resource) assigned to it.
- The tasks are divided into two kinds: Some are done by developers, others by researchers.
- I know that for this project I will have X (ex: 1.5) developers and Y researchers.

How can I have MS Project optimally assign developers to "developer tasks" and researchers to "researcher tasks"? I don't care which dev does which dev task etc. I just care about maximizing resource utilization per time.

Comment: Update: So far I've managed to come close by creating a single resource: Developer and giving it 250% availability. Likewise for a single Researcher resource. Now my problem is that auto levelling only makes use of "whole people". I.e. utilizes 200% of "Developer" and ignores the remaining 50%. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it automatically.
Assigning 250% to a resource would seem like you have 2,5 of that resource all the time. 
So you have to manually assign resources to tasks and then modify the resource availability from resource usage sheet or resource calendar. At this point if you level the resources it should make some of the things you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd let MSProject assign resources to work like I'd let a shovel dig a hole by itself.  The maximizing resource utilization will be valid at baseline line...and then invalid three seconds after.  Close enough is good enough.  Once the project starts, you will be dealing with a host of aleatory variability and chasing some "maximized" utilization is just a waste of time and will likely buy you nothing in terms of project results.

Comment: David: A. You're right. B. You mean well so thank you. C. That's not what I asked :)

Comment: I believe David's point is that putting efforts on trying to do it automatically will make the MSP not real once the first CR appears.